# Changing regional setting with Powershell

Tags: powershell, regional-settings

I have tried to google this out but with no success.
Is it possible to change the Decimal Separator to "." and Thousands Separator to "," in Powershell?

EDIT:  To be more precise, is it possible to change the system setting. As I would do manually in Control panel / regional settings...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show a sample and what exactly you wish to get also what you have tried please.

Comment: I have no example to show. I'm just asking if it is possible to change the system setting. As I would do manually in Control panel / regional settings

Comment: oo. Alright. Then its possible from the registry change

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to change at system level:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sDecimal -Value "."
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sThousand -Value ","
```

If you want to change at thread level:

```
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
$culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."
$culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ","
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
```

Then you can get the expected output:

```
[double]$x = 12345.67890
"{0:N2}" -f $x
```

Here is the output:

```
12,345.68
```

Comment: Just for future reference, Reza's answer totally worked but instead of 'sGrouping' in second example, 'sThousand' should be used

Comment: @Mario Thanks for the correction. In such cases when you find an important typo or an obvious mistake in an answer, feel free to edit the answer.